# how to return comma separated values that DOESN'T exists in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make tags table that accepts new tags from users.

I want to Exclude the general words from being inserted in the tags table like "the" or "that"

my idea is to make a general words table and exclude them while inserting the new tags.

this is how i work on php:

```
//get the general words from database and convert them into ary_general

//execlude the general words from the new words and store the rest into ary_tags

//insert the ary_tags words into tags table if doesn't exist.
```

but i wish in one statement do it all if I can:

Example:

source: "do,you,think,that,programming,is,cool"

```
tbl_general_words
do
you
that
is
```

result:
"think,programming,cool"

Comment: You could do it very easily if each word were in its own row instead of stored as a comma-separated list

Comment: do you mean the source string, or the general table?

Comment: Please show a table schema for `tags` table

Comment: Why only one statement?
Why not fetch the words you're stripping and if the individual word in a sentence is not in that array, add it to tags?
The overhead with prepared statements is very small, especially if you're not working with large datasets.
And if you *are* working with large data sets, you can create a prepared statement that inserts all of the words that aren't in that array at once.

Comment: I thought it would be a better idea for saving database requests load, because I will have to select all the general words every time i try to check the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The one statement approach can work

```
<?php
//needs to be configured appropriately
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
// fetch associative arrays, I normally use objects myself though
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// split the string in question into words
$wordsToTag = explode(" ", $phraseToTag);
// create a holder for the common words
$commonWords = array();
// prepare and execute the statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT word FROM tbl_general_words");
$stmt->execute();
// add the words to the array
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $commonWords[] = $row['word'];
}
// get the words that are not common
$wordsToTag = array_diff($commonWords, $wordsToTag);
// build your SQL string
$sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ";
// fore each word, we'll need a ? to hold the paramater
foreach($wordsToTag as $wordToTag)
{
    $sql .= "(?), ";
}
// remove the trailing space and trailing comma
// this could be achieved with an array and join instead if you prefer
$sql = rtrim(trim($sql), ",");
// add the words
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($wordsToTag);
?>
```

However, I recommend doing it as an iterated approach because it's cleaner.

```
<?php
// the code is the same until the adding part
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$wordsToTag = explode(" ", $phraseToTag);
$commonWords = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT word FROM tbl_general_words");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $commonWords[] = $row['word'];
}

$wordsToTag = array_diff($commonWords, $wordsToTag);
// prepare the statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tags SET tag = ?");
foreach($wordsToTag as $wordToTag)
{
    // change the param and execute, because prepared statements are designed for this
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $wordToTag);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_tags (word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO temporary_tags VALUES ('do'),('you'),('think'),('that'),('programming'),('is'),('cool');
-- mysql_query("INSERT INTO temporary_tags VALUES ('", implode("'),('", $arr_tags), "');")
INSERT INTO tags (tagColumn, someIntColumn, someStrColumn)
    SELECT temporary_tags.word, 5, 'string value' 
    FROM temporary_tags 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_general_words ON tbl_general_words.word = temporary_tags.word 
    WHERE tbl_general_words.word IS NULL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_tags;
```